# pytest - mock exception of method to test Flask API

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, pytest, magicmock

i'd like to unit test the following Flask API using pytest and mock:

```
    #api.py
    @api.route("/get_job/<job_name>")
        class JobStatus(Resource):
            @api.marshal_with(m_res)
            def get(self, job_name):
                try:
                    job_status = gcp.generate_signed_url("bucket_name", blob_path)
                except ValueError as e:
                    try:
                        client = kube.SparkApplicationClient()
                        job_status = client.get(job_name)["status"]["applicationState"]["state"]
                    except ApiException as e:
                        abort(404, "job doesn't exist: %s\n" % e)
                return {"job_status": job_status}
```

i wrote the following test for the case when both exception are sent but the patches don't work:

```
    #test_api.py    
    import pytest
    from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock
    from kubernetes.client.rest import ApiException
    from api import server
        
    @pytest.fixture
    def app():
        app = server.app
        return app
        
        
    @patch("api.gcp.generate_signed_url", MagicMock(side_effect=Exception(ValueError)))
    @patch("api.kube.SparkApplicationClient.get", MagicMock(side_effect=Exception(ApiException)))
    def test_get_job_status_doesnt_exists(client):
        response = client.get(
            "/api/get_job/68987af5-ccf4-4c11-a89a-d6645b7f7"
        )
        assert response.status_code == 404
```

basically i'm trying to get `gcp.generate_signed_url` & `client.get(job_name)` to raise an exception while testing

thanks!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
@patch(
  "api.gcp.generate_signed_url", 
  side_effect=ValueError)
)
```

And:

```
@patch(
  "api.kube.SparkApplicationClient.get",
  **{
    'return_value.get.side_effect': ApiException
  }
)
```